# Level curves of a joint normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I need to plot the level curves of a joint distribution of two standard normal distributions.

I'm trying to proof that level curves are circumferences.

$$p_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)=c\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\Leftrightarrow\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)=2\pi c\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\Leftrightarrow\ln\left(\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)\right)=\ln\left(2\pi c\right)\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\Leftrightarrow\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}=\ln\left(2\pi c\right)\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}=-2\ln\left(2\pi c\right)$$

Is this a correct proof that level lines are circumferences here? I'm a bit confused about the minus in the last equation.

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}/2\pi$ takes values in $(0,1/2\pi]$ so if $c>2\pi$ this equation has no solution. If $c\in (0,1/2\pi]$ the log is weakly negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. Regarding the minus: when you wrote

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)=c,$$

then you are implicitly assuming that such a $c$ exists. In other words you can not put a $c$ there which is larger than the maximum value of the left side i.e. $\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}\right)$. Finally the maximum of this expression is $1/{2\pi}$. Therefore $0<c<\frac{1}{2\pi}$ whichch gives $-2\pi c>0$. Hope this clarifies your doubt.